# Root debug FS doesn't complete

Tags: root-access

When I run root debug FS, I get this error on part one:

[image]

On part two:

[image]

After that:

[image]

When I hit no:

[image]

I've followed all the instructions (debugging, unknown sources, drivers, etc) and it doesn't work.

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Stellar (4.1.2 jb, Model # SCH-I200, baseband I200VRBME1). What's wrong?

Comment: It failed already in step 1, so the other steps missed the base to operate on (they require those 3 files to be there). Without a closer look at the script, it's hard to say what went wrong there: `/data/local` is usualy world read- and writeable. I'd contact the author of the script with that; it's hard to solve that here on a Q&A site.